# Роутинг во Flight PHP

Tags: php, маршрутизация

Приветствую. Если тут есть знатоки этого микро-фреймворка, буду признателен за помощь.
Нужно создать скрипт для добавление учетной записи в бд.

```
<form>
<input type="text" name="email" placeholder="email" required ></br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>

Flight::route('POST /hello', function() {
  $db=Flight::db()->connect;
  Flight::register('usersmanager','UsersManager');
  $createuser=Flight::usersmanager()->createUser();
  $db=Flight::db()->disconnect;

Flight::redirect('/');
});



class UsersManager {
function createUser($info) {
    $data=$_POST;
if(isset($data['submit'])){
    $email = trim($data['email']);
    $query="INSERT INTO users('email') VALUES('$email')";
    mysql_query($query);
}
```

Не добавляет никаких данных, может что упускаю из вида??

Answer (score 0):

**1.**
Убедитесь что у вас заданы правильные параметры подключения к базе данных.
Например у меня так:

```
$driver_options = [PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND=>"SET NAMES 'UTF8'"];
Flight::register('db', 'PDO', ['mysql:host=localhost;dbname=DBNAME','DBUSER','DBPASS', $driver_options ]);
```

Код должен распологаться перед `Flight::route`

**2.**
Строки `connect` / `disconnect` удаляйте.

**3.**
Не нужно использовать глобальный массив `$_POST` → все данные запроса можно получить через `Flight::request()->data` например

```
$email = trim( Flight::request()->data->email );
```

**4.**
Не проверяйте `isset($data['submit'])` → вы уже знаете что получили POST запрос с данными. → Лучше проверьте корректность самих данных.

**5.**
Запрос к БД лучше выполнить средствами фреймворка предварительно подготовив запрос:

```
  $query = Flight::db()->prepare("INSERT INTO users ( 'email' ) VALUES( :useremail );");
  $query->execute(['useremail'=>$email]);
```